# Change element's height on top without scroll jump

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list with 100 elements. Elements' height is fixed, e.g. 100px.
But one element is 300px.

Looks like this:

```
===
Element 1
===
===
.
Element 2 (the big one)
.
===
===
Element 3
===
===
Element 4
===
...etc...
```

When we scroll down (for example, we scrolled to the "Element 40"), our 2nd Element's height decreases to 100px, like the others. I'm doing it via React.

The problem is, there's a jump in Safari iOS. Top elements' height reduces, and all elements are shifting up. Other browsers work well.

How can I avoid it?

If I use `window.scrollTo(...)` after the element collapsed, I also see a jump, because touchscroll goes smoothly.

```js
const Block = ({ height, text }) => {
  return <div className="block" style={{ height: `${height}px` }}>{text}</div>
};


const App = () => {

  // set 2nd element as a big one
  const [bigElementIndex, setBigElementIndex] = React.useState(1);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [])

  const list = [ ...Array(100) ].map((_, i) => {
    const height = i === bigElementIndex ? 300 : 100;
    return <Block key={i} height={height} text={`Block ${i}`} />;
  });
  
  const handleScroll = e => {
    // when we scroll enough, make element smaller
    if ( window.scrollY > 2000 ) {
      setBigElementIndex(null);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">{list}</div>
  )

};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.block {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: If the element is a block in the page, I cannot imagine a way of preventing the page from jumping once all the elements below it will have to be repositioned to fill up the empty space left by the new resized element. Which effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @julianobrasil just avoid the jump. Like in Chrome, for example. If you run the Snippet via Chrome, you wouldn't see any jump

Comment: You could try to add 200px to the scrolled position right after `setBigElementIndex(null);`.. Like `window.scrollY = window.scrollY + 200`. I am real unsure that will work and if it works, a tiny jumpy glitch will probably be noticable..

Comment: Yes, it is noticable, I tried it. I just thought there's some common use case for this kind of task